# Session not being sent from page to page in php

Tags: php, session, phpmyadmin

Hello i am making a big website ( a business ) 
My whole site was working fine then it went down then the sessions stopped working.
My login script is working fine it is getting the post and making it into a session ( it is saving the username into a session )

Here is my code

```
<?php


include('sesion/session.php') ;

include_once('config.php');



trim($_POST['usr_email']);
trim($_POST['usr_pass']);

$username = $_POST['usr_email'];
$password = $_POST['usr_pass'];

if(!preg_match("/^[-a-z0-9 ']{4,12}+$/i",$_POST['usr_email'])){
    echo "Username  email error";
    exit();
}

$sqlquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$username' AND password = '".md5($password)."'");

if (mysql_num_rows($sqlquery) > 0) {

    $sqldata = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery);
    $_SESSION['USERID'] = $sqldata['userid'];
    $_SESSION['LOGGEDIN'] = true;



$_SESSION['username'] = $username ;

$_SESSION['nickyyyyyyy'] = "nickyyyyyy" ;

    echo "<script>window.location.href='http://mysite.com/index2.php';</script>";

} else {
    echo "login error opps somthing was wrong ";


}



?>
```

That is the login script
has you can see ive done a test variable 
 $_SESSION['nickyyyyyyy'] = "nickyyyyyy" ;

Which is not being sent though. The page the session ent showing on is here

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head> 
    <title>URL Shortener</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="short links, tinyurl, bitly, bit.ly, earn money, link advertising, tiny url, url shortener">
    <meta name="description" content="Earn cash for each visitor to your shortened url links with URL Shortener!">
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
    <meta name="author" content="Nadeem Syed &lt;nsyed19@gmail.com, nsyed.com&gt;">
    <meta name="designer" content="Nadeem Syed">
    <meta name="copyright" content="Copyright 2011">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8; IE=9">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index2_files/jq.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index2_files/style.css">
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://nsyed.com/p/urls/js/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index2_files/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index2_files/jquery_004.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index2_files/jquery_002.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index2_files/jquery_003.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<?php

                include('sesion/session.php') ;
 include('config.php') ;



?>
    <div class="main_ctr">
        <div class="logo" style="float: left;">
            <a href="http://nsyed.com/p/urls/index.php"></a>
        </div>
                <?php

                include('sections/head.php') ;

                ?>
        <div class="error_box" style="display:none;"></div><div class="message_box" style="display:none;"></div>        <noscript>
            <div style="padding: 5px; background-color: red; color: #ffffff; text-align:center; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                Your browser currently does not support javascript or you have javascript turned off.
                This site will have very limited functionality without javascript.
                Please use a modern browser with javascript or enable the javascript option.
            </div>
        </noscript>
                <div class="shrink">
            <form action="index3.php" method="POST" style="margin:0;">
                <div class="nspr outeri left"></div>
                <div class="nspr outeri bg">
                    <div class="nspr inneri left"></div>
                    <div class="nspr inneri bg">
                        <input style="width: 569px;" name="adb_url" class="shrinker" value="http://" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="nspr inneri bg nblu">
                        <input style="opacity: 0.7;" name="adb_sub" class="shrinker" value="SHRINK!" type="submit">
                    </div>
                    <div class="nspr inneri right nblu"></div>
                </div>
                                    <div class="ml_options">
                        <div class="nspr outeri bg">More Options</div>
                        <div class="nspr outeri right"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    <div style="display: none; height: 0px;" class="ml_options_box">
                        <span style="float:left;width:125px;margin-top:6px;">Advertising Type:</span>
                        <span style="float:left;">
                            <select style="width:200px;" name="advert_type">
                                <option selected="selected" value="1">Interstitial Advert ($$$$$)</option>
                                <option value="2">Framed Banner ($$$)</option>
                                <option value="3">No Advert</option>
                            </select>
                        </span>
                        <div style="clear:both;height:10px;"></div>
                        <span style="float:left;width:125px;margin-top:6px;">Custom Name:</span>
                        <span style="float:left;">
                            <input name="custom_name" maxlength="40" style="width: 200px;" type="text">
                        </span>
                    </div>
                            </form>
        </div>
        <h2 class="page_title">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION[username] ; ?></h2><div class="user_content" style="text-align:center;">
    <strong>Today:</strong> 0 views, $0.00000 earned
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <strong>Total:</strong> 0 views, $0.00000 earned
</div>
<div class="user_content"><h2>Announcements</h2>

<?php
 include('Announcements.php') ;

?>


        </p>

    <h2>
        <span id="report_date">May 2011</span> Report
        <div style="float: right; font-weight: normal;">
            Choose Month:
            <select name="report_date">
                <option selected="selected" value="5-2011">May 2011</option><option value="4-2011">April 2011</option><option value="3-2011">March 2011</option><option value="2-2011">February 2011</option><option value="1-2011">January 2011</option>           </select>
        </div>
    </h2>
    <div id="report_graph" style="height: 300px; margin: 0pt auto; position: relative;"><canvas height="300" width="816"></canvas><canvas style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" height="300" width="816"></canvas><div class="tickLabels" style="font-size:smaller"><div class="xAxis x1Axis" style="color:#545454"><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:6px;top:287px;width:26px">1</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:32px;top:287px;width:26px">2</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:59px;top:287px;width:26px">3</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:85px;top:287px;width:26px">4</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:111px;top:287px;width:26px">5</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:138px;top:287px;width:26px">6</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:164px;top:287px;width:26px">7</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:190px;top:287px;width:26px">8</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:216px;top:287px;width:26px">9</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:243px;top:287px;width:26px">10</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:269px;top:287px;width:26px">11</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:295px;top:287px;width:26px">12</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:322px;top:287px;width:26px">13</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:348px;top:287px;width:26px">14</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:374px;top:287px;width:26px">15</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:401px;top:287px;width:26px">16</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:427px;top:287px;width:26px">17</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:453px;top:287px;width:26px">18</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:479px;top:287px;width:26px">19</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:506px;top:287px;width:26px">20</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:532px;top:287px;width:26px">21</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:558px;top:287px;width:26px">22</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:585px;top:287px;width:26px">23</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:611px;top:287px;width:26px">24</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:637px;top:287px;width:26px">25</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:664px;top:287px;width:26px">26</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:690px;top:287px;width:26px">27</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:716px;top:287px;width:26px">28</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:742px;top:287px;width:26px">29</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:769px;top:287px;width:26px">30</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;left:795px;top:287px;width:26px">31</div></div><div class="yAxis y1Axis" style="color:#545454"><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:274px;right:804px;width:12px">0</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:246px;right:804px;width:12px">1</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:219px;right:804px;width:12px">2</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:192px;right:804px;width:12px">3</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:165px;right:804px;width:12px">4</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:138px;right:804px;width:12px">5</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:110px;right:804px;width:12px">6</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:83px;right:804px;width:12px">7</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:56px;right:804px;width:12px">8</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:29px;right:804px;width:12px">9</div><div class="tickLabel" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;top:2px;right:804px;width:12px">10</div></div></div></div>
    <table class="report_info" cellspacing="2">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td><span id="report_date">May 2011</span></td>
            <td>Visitors: <span id="report_info_visitors">
            <?php
            $result123 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM urls_non_loggedin WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]'");

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result123);

echo $num_rows ;



            ?>

            </span></td>
            <td>Avg. CPM: $<span id="report_info_cpm">0.00</span></td>
            <td>Month Earned: $<span id="report_info_earned">


<?php

$sql66 =  "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$_SESSION[username]'";
$result66 = mysql_query($sql66) or die(mysql_error());
$battle_get66 = mysql_fetch_array($result66);

echo $battle_get66['credit'] ;
?>


            </span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>
<div class="user_content">
    <h2>Your Links</h2>
    <table class="tablesorter links_table" cellspacing="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="22%">Website Address</th>

                <th width="30%">Shortened Address</th>
                <th width="13%"></th>
                <th width="18%">Views</th>
                <th align="center"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody><tr id="no_link"><td colspan="5"><em>



        <table width="" height="81" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>        <?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM urls_non_loggedin WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


while($values=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo $values['start_ur'] ;
echo "<p>  </p>";


}
        ?> </td>
    <td>    <?php
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM urls_non_loggedin WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());


while($values2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){

echo "http://geatzo.com/view.php?id=".$values2['End_url'];
echo "<p>  </p>";

}
        ?> </td>
    <td>

    <?php
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM urls_non_loggedin WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]'";
$result3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die(mysql_error());


while($values3=mysql_fetch_array($result3)){

echo $values3['clicks'];
echo "<p>  </p>";
}



        ?>

     </td>




        </em></td></tr></tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="_lp"></div>
</div>
<div class="user_content">
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
        <h2>Top 20 Countries</h2>
        <table class="tablesorter top_countries" style="width: 90%;" cellspacing="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th align="right">Views</th>

                    <th align="right">Money Earned</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody><tr><td colspan="3"><em>No data available</em></td></tr></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
        <h2>Top 20 Referrers</h2>
        <table class="tablesorter top_referrers" style="width: 90%;" cellspacing="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Referrer</th>
                    <th align="right">Views</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody><tr><td colspan="2"><em>No data available</em></td></tr></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>


        <div class="footer">
            <span style="float:left;">
                © Copyright 2011 URL Shortener v1.2.5           </span>
            <span style="float:right;">
                <a href="http://nsyed.com/p/urls/advertising.php">Advertising Rates</a> | 
                <a href="http://nsyed.com/p/urls/rates.php">Publisher Payouts</a> |
                <a href="http://ghfgh.com/p/urls/privacy.php">Privacy</a> |
                <a href="http://hghfg.com/p/urls/terms.php">Terms</a> | 
                <a href="http://ghfg.com/p/urls/faq.php">FAQ</a> | 
                <a href="http://nsygfhhgfed.com/p/urls/contact.php">Contact</a>
            </span>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body></html>
```

In side the sesions file i inculde on all pages is just
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);

the login script logs in and saves the session vairables ( i toke the redirect out and put a print sessions there and checked but when it goes to the index.2php there is no session set :S

Answer (score 6):

You have to include

```
session_start();
```

before you send html-code.

So put

```
include('sesion/session.php') ;
```

at the top of that page, before the HTML.

Comment: deleted my comment ^ what this guy said

Comment: Thanks so much the hard stuff i can do butt he easy things i forget lol :) thanks